# How to rebuild my google cloud Compute Engine VM instance like Linode VPS?

Tags: google-compute-engine, linode

I am going to migrate my server from Linode to Google Cloud recently. When I am testing the google cloud Compute Engine VM instance, I can not find out the rebuild button like Linode.

Now I did some wrong operation on my VM instance, so I need to rebuild it. I don't want to delete it because I don't want to change the IP address.

I have tried the "reset" operation, but it is useless. I

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Cloud Platform does not have the rebuild button. As I understand you don't want to loose your external IP address. I recommend you to reserve the ephemeral IP address of your actual instance, create a new one with a screenshot and then assign the reserved IP address.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to the External IP addresses page in the GCP Console. In the Type column, change the address type to Static for the IP address you want to promote. Provide a name for the new static IP address and click Reserve.
2. Stop the old instance.
3. Create a new instance with the snapshot and select the reserved IP address.